# Solve $\sqrt{(x-2)(x-3)}+5\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{x-3}}=\sqrt{x^2+6x+8}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> Solve $\sqrt{(x-2)(x-3)}+5\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{x-3}}=\sqrt{x^2+6x+8}$

\begin{align*}
    &\Leftrightarrow (\sqrt{(x-2)(x-3)}+5\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{x-3}})^2=(\sqrt{x^2+6x+8})^2 \tag{1}\\
    &\Leftrightarrow (x-2)(x-3)+\dfrac{25(x-2)}{x-3}+10(x-2)=x^2+6x+8 \tag{2}\\
    &\Leftrightarrow x^2-5x+6+\dfrac{25x-50}{x-3}+10x-20=x^2+6x+8 \tag{3}\\
    &\Leftrightarrow 5x-14+\dfrac{25x-50}{x-3}=6x+8 \tag{4}\\
    &\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{(5x-14)(x-3)}{x-3}+\dfrac{25x-50}{x-3}=6x+8 \tag{5}\\
    &\Leftrightarrow 5x^2-17x+42+25x-50=6x^2-18x+8x-24 \tag{6}\\
    &\Leftrightarrow x^2-18x-16=0 \tag{7}\\
    &\Leftrightarrow x=\dfrac{18 \pm \sqrt{324+64}}{2} = \dfrac{18 \pm 2\sqrt{97}}{2}=9 \pm \sqrt{97} \tag{8}
\end{align*}

But the answer is $x=8, -2$. I feel my calculations are correct but clearly they aren't.

Comment: $x=-2$ is clearly wrong, it makes the right hand side to zero.

Comment: [The correct answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+sqrt%28%28x-2%29%28x-3%29%29%2B5*sqrt%28%28x-2%29%2F%28x-3%29%29%3Dsqrt%28x%5E2%2B6x%2B8%29)

Comment: How is it possible to get $x=\frac{3}{4}$ by hand?

Comment: By taking the case $x<2$.

Comment: Setting the expression to $y$ and using a computer to do the squaring and factoring I get $$(4 x^4 y^2-x^2 y^4-42 x^3 y^2+6 x y^4-441 x^4+262 x^2 y^2\\-9 y^4+4452 x^3-820 x y^2-15604 x^2+912 y^2+22048 x-10816)\cdot \\
(4 x^4 y^2-x^2 y^4-2 x^3 y^2+6 x y^4-x^4-58 x^2 y^2-9 y^4\\+12 x^3+20 x y^2-4 x^2+192 y^2-192 x-256)=0$$ The latter factor has tangent cones around the intersections with $y=0$ $(x+8)^2-120y^2=0$ and $(x+2)^2=0.$ For the former I get $45(3x-4)^2-32y^2=0$ and $245(7x-26)^2-432y^2=0.$ As you can see I get one spurious solution from each factor.

Comment: This is too complicated for me to understand sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $(5)$ to $(6)$, instead of $$(5x-14)(x-3)=5x^2-17x+42$$ it should be $$(5x-14)(x-3)=5x^2-29x+42$$

This results in the final equation being $$x^2-6x-16=0,$$

with roots $x=8,-2$ as desired.

However, from $(1)$ to $(2)$, you have used $\sqrt{(x-2)(x-3)}\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{x-3}}=x-2$, which assumes $x-2\geq 0$, so the only solution when $x\geq 2$ is $8$.

You should now consider the case $x<2$, substituing $\sqrt{(x-2)(x-3)}\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{x-3}}=2-x$.

Comment: I understand how $\sqrt{(x-2)^2}=x-2$ or $-(x-2)$. But assuming $\sqrt{(x-2)^2}=2-x$, how did you come up with $x<2$?

Comment: I did not assume $\sqrt{(x-2)^2}=2-x$. You considered the case $x\ge 2$ (otherwise the above mentioned equality is not true). When $x<2$, one has $\sqrt{(x-2)^2}=|x-2|=2-x$.

Comment: $x=-2$ does not work in the original equation. I suppose this is because we have squared the original equation so it has changed. Then $x=-2$ is an extraneous solution?

Comment: Well, in the first place $x=-2$ doesn't work because we are assuming $x\ge 2$ and we shouldn't even consider it in this case. Nonetheless, as squaring an equation is not a reversible process we may sometimes get solutions to the squared equation which are not valid for the original one.

Comment: @JulioPuerta In this case, when both sides are positive, squaring in (1) is, in fact, equivalent. The problem is rather in (2) where the absolute value is missing.

Comment: @A.Γ.  I know. That is why I said 'sometimes' and not this time.